# Get value of a column of a row where select option value changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I am trying to model a webpage which allows users to give ratings to some projects and store these ratings in the background. I have a table like this
Project Id|Title|Rating. In rating column I have conditionally select tags in some columns otherwise there is some text. I added an onchange event on select which triggered a javascript function when value of option is changed, But i want to extract the value of project_id feild of the row where select value was changed. I am a newbie in javascript so I couldnt find anything which could solve my problem, I need that project id value because i need to store that value in my database which I have got it working via Ajax Calls.Here is my table below:
Code:

```
<?php if($row['status']==='complete' && $result2->num_rows==0 )
            { ?>

                <select id="rating select" onchange="rating()" class="form-control" name="projectrating">
                    <option selected>0</option>
                    <option  value="1" >1</option>
                    <option  value="2">2</option>
                    <option  value="3">3</option>
                    <option  value="4">4</option>
                    <option  value="5">5</option>
                </select>

            <?php } ?> 

                <?php if($row['status']==='complete' && $result2->num_rows > 0 )
            {   $row2=$result2->fetch_assoc();
                $rating=$row2['rating'];
                echo "You have already rated this Project!,You have given the project a rating of $rating";
              } ?>

            <?php
            if($row['status']!=='complete') { ?>
               <?php echo "Ratings only for complete projects" ?>





           <?php } ?>
                  </td>
            <?php } ?>
```

Javascript:( I need to fill variable parameter without value so I can send it using Ajax to a php script.)

```
<script>

    function rating()
    {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        if(this.status===400){
        alert("There was a problem while giving the rating");
    }
        if(this.status===200)
        {

            alert("Rating given succesfully");
            window.location.reload(true);


        }

            }
  };   
        xhttp.open("POST", "rating.php", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var param= 
        xhttp.send(param);

        }
```

Comment: what is **rating()** funtion? please show your js too

Comment: posted javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option

**Option1:**

1. Using closest tr and children, you can get complete row values on change
2. Each cell can be obtained by "eq().text()"

Codepen -https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/YVERRv

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('select').on('change',function(){
   var $td= $(this).closest('tr').children('td');
  var project= $td.eq(0).text();
  console.log(project)
})
                            })
```

**Option 2:** Using plain javascript with parentElement and childNodes and using rating() onchange function

HTML:

```
<select  onchange="rating(this)" class="form-control" name="projectrating">
```

JS:

```
function rating(a){
  console.log((a.parentElement) .parentElement.childNodes[1].innerHTML)
}
```

a.parentElement will give the td enclosing select and parentElement of it is tr element and first child innerHTML gives the first column value

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/qmVQwp

Comment: Hi can this be done in java script? I dont know much about jQuery Library.

Comment: Please check my second codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/qmVQwp using plain javascript

Comment: Glad it helped your question.. please mark it as answered if it is helpful for you :)

Comment: Can you tell me how does this work? Its absolutely brilliant.

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it is helpful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

first, you can't use multiple ID for one element

```
<select id="rating" onchange="rating()" class="form-control" name="projectrating">
```

then you should determine what you want to send

```
var paramToSend = document.getElementById("rating").value;
```

so your js will gonna be like this

```
function rating(){
var paramToSend = document.getElementById("rating").value;
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        if(this.status===400){
            alert("There was a problem while giving the rating");
        }
        if(this.status===200){
            alert("Rating given succesfully");
            //window.location.reload(true);
        }

    }
};   
xhttp.open("POST", "rating.php", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var param="postedParam=" + paramToSend ;    
xhttp.send(param); }
```

so in your rating.php you will get **$_POST['postedParam']**